# Wrong content of binary test resources when using ClassLoader InputStream

Tags: java, testing, junit, classloader, binaryfiles

I have a binary file in test resources `src/test/resources/file.bin`:

```sh
$ ls -la src/test/resources

-rw-r--r-- 1 g4s8 g4s8 5125 Apr 30 19:53 file.bin
```

I'm using it for tests to verify some class.
Before testing, I need to copy the content to the file-system, I'm using `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` to read the data:

```java
@Test
public void readsContent(@TempDir final Path tmp) throws Exception {
    final ClassLoader clo = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    final Path file = Files.createFile(tmp.resolve("file.bin"));
    try (
        final InputStream res = new BufferedInputStream(clo.getResourceAsStream("file.bin"));
        final OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(file, StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.WRITE))
    ) {
        byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
        for (int read = res.read(buf); read >= 0; read = res.read(buf)) {
            out.write(buf, 0, read);
        }
    }
    // test code
}
```

But the content of this file is bigger than expected and it differ from what was in resource file:

```sh
$ ls -la /tmp/junit18423574017636618834/

-rw-r--r-- 1 g4s8 g4s8 9350 May  1 12:22 file.bin
```

The result file is `9350` bytes of size, but source file was `5125`.
With hex editor I investigated that only first two bytes of these files are the same, all other data is different:
[image]

What's wrong with my code? Why this file can't be read correctly using standard way via `ClassLoader`?

Comment: No reason for that here, although `> 0` would make more sense than `>= 0`. Are you looking at the right input and output files?

Comment: @user207421 thanks. Yes, I'm sure that files are correct, I checked it via debugger, with console logs, from ide and from maven build, tried to clean and rebuild. Also, I tried to use direct absolute file location (`/project/path/src/test/resources/file.bin` with same code, and it was fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by enabled `filtering` [Maven option](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) inherited from parent `pom.xml`, it seems Maven managed to find and replace some patterns in binary file, and IDE uses Maven to prepare test resources:

```xml
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
  </build>
```

I've overridden this option in project's `pom.xml`, and it's working now:

```xml
<build>
  <testResources>
    <testResource>
      <directory>${basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
      <filtering>false</filtering>
    </testResource>
  </testResources>
</build>
```